# He is the hand of glory

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Wretched fools! You cannot stop the master. *He is the hand of glory!* His will shall be done.

This is from the video game Warcraft 3.

I understand the meaning of *hand of glory* on its own. But what does it mean in this context?

EDIT: More context here. The player's mission is to chase the enemy called Illidan. But he ordered his monsters/troops to stop the player from finishing the mission. This is the word spoken by one of his monster when the player encounters him. Is the context clearer now?

EDIT2: If the context is still unclear, this is the [video](https://youtu.be/s7xMnw1mMiA?t=469).

EDIT3: Sorry, my bad, I just saw the text without listening the audio and now I find the speaker says something else, something like "*his is the hand of glory*" to my non-native ear, which is not grammatical or "*he seized the...*", which is reasonable. Here is the [audio](https://media1.vocaroo.com/mp3/1gkeFOgntEPG), you guys could check it out.

Comment: It looks to me as if the writer of the game has heard the phrase and has no idea what it means, and thought it would sound good.

Comment: His is the hand of glory would be perfectly grammatical. Rather archaic perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't played the game so I don't know the context, but ...

I presume you know what "glory" means: Honor, praise, distinction, etc.

"Hand" of course literally means that part of your body you use to pick things up or manipulate them. Metaphorically, therefore, it means someone or something that takes action.

So the "hand of glory" is the person or thing that brings honor and praise.

If he "IS the hand of glory", than he is a person who brings honor and praise. In context, probably to himself.

If "his is the hand of glory", then he has the power to bring honor and praise.

Either way, pretty much  the same idea.